# Terraform update Route53 DOMAIN NameServers

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Is it possible to create terraform script to update domain name server? I want to update the nameservers on the domain itself, not the zone. The domain under "registered domains" needs to set the name servers to point to the zone's name servers.

I have this zone I made:

```
resource "aws_route53_zone" "redrebelgames" {
  name = "redrebelgames.com"
}
```

I can access the name servers using: `aws_route53_zone.redrebelgames.nameservers`

Does anyone know if this is possible without using a provisioner to run aws sdk methods locally? The only method I can think of is to use a "local-exec" provisioner which would then run a python or ruby script to directly call aws sdk methods. Basically what I am trying to figure out is if it's possible to run this function: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/APIReference/API_domains_UpdateDomainNameservers.html directly in Terraform, without using an external script.

Comment: I don't think you can do that without external script.

Comment: That's fine, I'm only asking this question because it's possible there's things I don't know. :)

Comment: What about `aws_route53_record`? You can update with it any kind of DNS record including name servers https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/route53_record#ns-and-soa-record-management

Comment: That is not the same thing as what I'm referring to. There's the records in zones and then there's the domain DNS itself.

Comment: I'd like to understand your use case. I assume, you don't like the random nameservers, but in that case you can use aws_route53_delegation_set. Are you trying to set non AWS IPs?

Comment: @ucipass I'm not sure what a delegation set is. But essentially, set the name servers after I create the zone. The domain name servers must point to the zone name servers

Comment: @Daniel, I assumed that you use Amazon Route 53 as your DNS service. In that case you can use aws_route53_delegation_set to always you the same 4 DNS server. If that's not the case I'd be curious why you would have a domain defined in route53 and not use Route 53 for your DNS service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just using a local-exec provisioner which runs this script that I wrote in ruby:

```
require 'aws-sdk-route53domains'

Aws.use_bundled_cert!

AWS_ACCESS_KEY = ARGV[0]
AWS_SECRET_KEY = ARGV[1]
name_servers = ARGV[2].to_s.split ','

# At the time of writing this, there is only one endpoint for route53domains, at us-east-1, see link below
# https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/r53.html
client = Aws::Route53Domains::Client.new(
  region: "us-east-1",
  access_key_id: AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
  secret_access_key: AWS_SECRET_KEY
)

response = client.update_domain_nameservers({
  domain_name: "redrebelgames.com",
  nameservers: name_servers.map{|ns| {name: ns}}
})
```

Here is the terraform setup:

```
resource "aws_route53_zone" "redrebelgames" {
  name = "redrebelgames.com"

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "ruby scripts/update_domain_nameservers.rb ${var.AWS_ACCESS_KEY} ${var.AWS_SECRET_KEY} ${element(aws_route53_zone.redrebelgames.name_servers, 0)},${element(aws_route53_zone.redrebelgames.name_servers, 1)},${element(aws_route53_zone.redrebelgames.name_servers, 2)},${element(aws_route53_zone.redrebelgames.name_servers, 3)}"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As of May 2022, there's `aws_route53domains_registered_domain` resource on version `~> 4.0` of `hashicorp/aws`. For some reason, it's not taking effect. I'm posting this in case someone stumbles upon this Stack Overflow post in the future.

Update: it worked, I just need to wait for a few minutes. Or maybe it's because I ran `terraform apply` again, not really sure.